# SSIS Execute SQL Task Error "Single Row result set is specified, but no rows were returned."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am attempting what I thought was a relatively easy thing.  I use a SQL task to look for a filename in a table.  If it exists, do something, if not, do nothing.

Here is my setup in SSIS:

[image: SSIS Setup]

My SQL Statement in 'File Exists in Table' is as follows, and  ResultSet is 'Single Row':

```
SELECT ISNULL(id,0) as id FROM PORG_Files WHERE filename = ?
```

[image]

[image]

My Constraint is:

[image]

When I run it, there are no files in the table yet, so it should return nothing.  I've tried `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` to set a value.  I receive the following error:

> Error: 0xC002F309 at File Exist in Table, Execute SQL Task: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "id": "Single Row result set is specified, but no rows were returned.".

Not sure how to fix this.  The `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` are the things suggestions found in SO and on MSDN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your SQL statement to a `COUNT` then your comparison expression would read `@ID > 0`.  So, if you have files that match your pattern the count will be greater than 0 if there are no files it will return 0.

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) as id FROM PORG_Files WHERE filename = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a row exists then you should use Count as @jradich1234 mentioned.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as id FROM PORG_Files WHERE filename = ?
```

If you are looking to check if a row exists and to store the id in a variable to use it later in the package, first you have to use TOP 1 since you selecting a single row result set and you can use a similar logic:

```
DECLARE @Filename VARCHAR(4000) = ?

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PORG_Files WHERE filename = @Filename)
    SELECT TOP 1 id FROM PORG_Files WHERE filename = @Filename
ELSE
    SELECT 0 as id
```

Then if `id = 0` then no rows exists.

Answer (score 0):

It just needs to use UNION another row empty
always return a value

Like it if work for you

```
SELECT foo As nameA, fa AS nameB
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS nameA, NULL AS nameB
```

And then you can validated (line) contrained if var is null no allow [image]